# T-test using two dfs in R

Tags: r, t-test

I am trying to run a t-test to determine if a column in one df is significantly different from a column in another df. I have two dfs, "block 1" and "block 2". 
I have tried this code:

```r
  t.test(block1$Duration ~ block2$Duration,
       paired=FALSE, var.equal=TRUE)
```

And I received this error message:

> Error in t.test.formula(block1$Duration ~ block2$Duration, paired = FALSE, :
>     grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

Any insight into what I'm doing wrong is appreciated!

Comment: You want to compare the column block1$Duration to block2$Duration, thus you want the comma form and not the formula. `t.test(block1$Duration, block2$Duration, paired=FALSE, var.equal=TRUE)`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense-- thanks so much!