# Grouping factors in a pooled 2 sample t-test

Tags: r

I have a 2*2 table of 7 men and 11 women's weight (saved as weights_gender.csv), and aim to perform a pooled t-test. I have assigned the CSV file as `weight = read.csv("weights_gender.csv")`, but whenever I try to run `t.test(weight$men~weight$women, var.equal=TRUE)`, it keeps on printing this message:

> grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels.

What is the issue?

[image]

Comment: Hi can you please provide a reprex? I am going to guess you have missing values, try to check levels()

Comment: Without seeing how your data is structured, this is just a guess but I believe you are using the incorrect form of the t.test.  Above is the formula form while you need the comma form.  Try:  `t.test(men, women, var.equal=TRUE)`

Comment: I have updated further details. Does the issue come from the unbalance in number of data for 2 genders?

Comment: My previous comment stands, you need to use the comma to compare column 1 to column 2, similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62045080/t-test-using-two-dfs-in-r#comment109737308_62045080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ...

```r
t.test(x = weight$men, y = weight$women, var.equal = TRUE)
```

The way you were specifying the command it thought you wanted men's weight grouped by women which of course is not what you want.

Results...

```r
    Two Sample t-test

data:  weight$men and weight$women
t = 5.9957, df = 16, p-value = 1.867e-05
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 15.26250 31.95828
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 77.42857  53.81818
```

Data

```r
weight <- data.frame(
   men = c(88, 90, 78, 75, 70, 72, 69, NA, NA, NA, NA),
   women = c(45, 57, 54, 62, 60, 59, 44, 43, 67, 50, 51)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit "theoretical" so I'll make it more concrete

Here I make two data frames with data about men's and women's weights, and labeling them.

```
df_m <- tibble(weight = 170 + 30*rnorm(7), sex = "Male")
df_f <- tibble(weight = 130 + 30*rnorm(11), sex = "Female")
```

Next we combine the data and set `sex` to be a factor variable

```
df_all <- rbind(df_m, df_f)
df_all[, 'sex'] <- lapply(df_all[, 'sex'], as.factor)
```

Finally we apply the t-test.

```
t.test(weight ~ sex, data = df_all, var.equal = TRUE)
```

My result was

```
    Two Sample t-test

data:  weight by sex
t = -5.2104, df = 16, p-value = 8.583e-05
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -89.84278 -37.87810
sample estimates:
mean in group Female   mean in group Male 
            120.2316             184.0921
```